# If $x \in H$, show that $P_K(x)$ is characterized by the relations $(x, P_K(x)) = \Vert P_K(x)\Vert^2$ and $(x - P_K(x), y) = 0$ for all $y \in K$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

> Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space, let $K$ be a closed convex cone in $H$ with vertex at the origin. If $x \in H$, show that $P_K(x)$ is characterized by the relations $(x, P_K(x)) = \Vert P_K(x)\Vert^2$ and $(x - P_K(x), y) = 0$ for all $y \in K$.

Here, $P_K(x)$ is the convex projection of $x$ on $K$. This is characterized by $(x - P_K(x), y - P_K(x)) \leq 0$ for all $y \in K$.

I have managed to show that $(x, P_K(x)) = \Vert P_K(x)\Vert^2$ (successively putting $y = 2P_K(x), P_K(x)/2$), which gives $(x - P_K(x), y) \leq 0$. However, I am having trouble with the reverse inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this seems to be false.

Let $H=\mathbb R^2$,
$$
K=\{(a,b):\ b\geq |a|\}. 
$$
This is a convex cone that contains the origin. Let $x=(0,-1)$. Then $P_Kx=(0,0)$. And
$$
(x-P_Kx,(1,1))=((0,-1),(1,1))=-1<0. 
$$

The characterization does hold when $K$ is a subspace; in that case the argument is easy because you can use $y$ and $-y$.